# Bash, change whole word with tr

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, command, tr

I've been looking for a solution to my problem for some time now and was unable to find it. I must use linux `tr`-command to change whole words.
For instance, "ala, has" to "Ala, Has".
It should work like that, when I type "ala has a cat" - "Ala Has a cat".

But what I get whenever I pass it to terminal is: "ala Has a cat". Any ideas how to change whole parts of words using `tr`?

Also "alanna hasn't got a cat" should be changed to "Alanna Hasn't got a cat".

Comment: `tr` will do translation of one set to another, so you need something else e.g. `sed`

Comment: I know but that was the task given by my teacher. Any ideas?

Comment: @heemayl exactly, that's what I thought.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that is not possible with `tr`, since `tr` can't limit the replacements. You receive `ala Has a cat` because first `a` is replaced with `A` and then again with `a`. With `tr` it could alternatively look like:

```
echo "ala has a cat" | tr -ts "'[a]' '[h]'" "'[A]' '[H]'"
AlA HAs A cAt
```

But as I said, `tr` replaces or deletes multiple characters. For more info look at the man page `man tr` in Linux.

However, what you want can be achieved through `sed`. Here is it:

```
echo "ala has a cat" | sed -e 's/a/A/' -e 's/h/H/'
Ala Has a cat
```

The `-e` option adds more `sed`-operands, sort of logical AND. Adding `/g` at the end would be equivalent to the `tr`-comand.

Comment: Ok, thank You very much for the example. I guess I'll go ask my teacher what exactly did he have in mind.

Comment: @ninigi Yes, because it certainly looks strange. Was it specified to do it exactly with `tr`?

Comment: honestly, I'm not sure anymore.